# What word describes the act of converting a phrase into its opposite?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, linguistics

Turning a phrase negative (e.g. *good* → *not good*, and *a question* → *not a question*) is called [*negation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affirmative_and_negative). One can say "*I negated the phrase*".

What is the act of turning a phrase into its opposite (e.g. *good* → *bad* and *a question* → *an answer*) called? I'd like to say "*I **×**'d the phrase.*"

---

A [gerund](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund) sounds forced. "Oppositeing"? "Oppositising"? "Oppositeifying?" Maybe I'm getting too fixed on conjugating "opposite".

Comment: Negation can be observed, and precisely defined. "Opposite", on the other hand, is a very vague term; most terms have several dimensions in which they oppose other terms, and there is no special term for it. No reason to have a technical term for something that's not technical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went with **inversion**: “*I inverted the phrase.*”

This may not be the technical term, but it is very descriptive in context.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a phrase in this case. "Change something to/into antonym" or "convert something to/into antonym".

There is no single verb that can describe it.